# Jenkins, how to add variable content to file

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How can I add variable content in file?

```
sh "ssh root@${host} 'echo '$vari' > text.txt'"
```

This gives empty file

Without variable it works:

```
sh "ssh root@${host} 'echo some text > text.txt'"
```

Comment: Do you need those extra ticks around the variable? Think the shell won’t handle this properly. Did you try without the ticks around the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`writeFile`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) command offered by Jenkins:

```
writeFile file: "text.txt", text: YOUR_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score -1):

This are 2 ways how you can write the content of a variable to a file:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        VAR = "hello world!"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Write to file'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo "${VAR}" > test.txt'
                sh "echo ${VAR} >> test.txt"
                sh 'cat test.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[test] Running shell script
+ echo hello world!
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo hello world!
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ cat test.txt
hello world!
hello world!
```